# Help me identify pin of this LED Matrix PCB

Tags: pcb, identification, pinout, led-matrix

LED Matrix bicolors (Orange/Green)

PCB board of 10 LED Matrix of 4 x 8 (LTP23548AA-NB)

It looks like J3 is regular UART|USB. I'm trying to find what J1 and J2 are about. The goal is to add a controller to this board.

[image: PCB board of 10 LED Matrix of 4 x 8 (LTP23548AA-NB)]

Answer (score 0):

J3 is power. Com means common aka ground and 5V is well, 5V.

J1 is input for whats likely the microcontroller u12 or u11 in charge of the TPIC6B595 shift registers used.

J2 is likely a cascading output.

Since u12 and u11 are unmarked, if anyone knows the protocol required is anyone's guess. U15 is a latch or decade counter likely used to cycle through the shift registers or to multiplex the led sections, part of a clocking system (a guess).

Since the board is made up of shift registers, you can trace out the circuit and replace the microcontroller. Shift register led circuits are relatively simple with considerable online code examples.

Alternatively look up the manufacturer and see what similar publicly available boards they have. Custom private boards tend to be very similar to the off the shelf ones.